# How to prove the following the set are equal

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

> Let $D$ be an open convex subset of $\mathbf R^d$ with boundary $\partial D$ and closure $\overline D$.
> For $x\in\mathbf R^d$ and a unit vector $e$ let $L_{x,e}=\{x+\lambda e, \lambda\ge0\}$ be the ray drawn from $x$ in the direction $e$.
> For $x\in\mathbf R^d$, let $$D(x)=\{y\in \mathbf R^d \colon L_{x,y/|y|} \cap \overline D \ne \emptyset\}.$$
> In particular, $D(x)=\overline D$ for all $x\in D$. Furthermore, for $y\in D(x)$, let
> $$\lambda(x,y/|y|)=\max\{R>0 \colon x+Ry/|y| \in \overline D\}.$$

(From Vassili Kolokoltsov: *On fully mixed and multidimensional extensions of the Caputo and Riemann-Liouville derivatives, related Markov processes and fractional differential equations*, [arXiv:1501.03925](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03925), [DOI: 10.1515/fca-2015-0060](https://doi.org/10.1515/fca-2015-0060).

[image]

Look at the above picture, let us consider a simple case if $d=2$. How to show $D(x)=\bar{D}, x\in D$?  This results seems a little bit strange. If $x\in D$, then  $L_{x,y/{|y|}}\cap \bar{D}\neq \varnothing$ forever. So $D(x)=R^2,$ why $D(x)=\bar{D}, x\in D$? Is there some misunderstanding? Please correct it.

Comment: Could you say where the quoted text is from: which textbook or article?

Comment: this article is "On Fully Mixed and Multidimensional Extensions of the Caputo and Riemann-Liouville Derivatives, Related Markov Processes and Fractional Differential Equations" On page 1049.

Comment: Thanks to @MartinSleziak for editing in the text from the picture, and including the reference!  @‍AiliyEvans, for future reference, that is the appropriate way to proceed if a significant part of a post can only be understood from reference to an image.

Comment: Could some of the close voters comment as to why?  On the face of it, this seems an okay question (now improved due to edit): it is asking about a research paper which, indeed, does seem to contain an error.  My understanding of the definition is that $D(x)$ is the entire unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$, if $x\in D$, because $D$ is open.  I guess if I knew more about the area, I could hazard a guess as to what was meant, but I don't.

Comment: I don't even see why $D$ needs to be open. If I'm understanding correctly, $x$ is in $L_{x,e}$ for any $e$, so if $x\in D$ then $L_{x,e}\cap D\neq\emptyset$ for any $e$.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: In my opinion, the correct thing to do for the OP would be to contact the author and ask for clarifications. It is obvious, even for 1st year of college, that the statement under discussion is wrong, so there is nothing more for us to say (we shouldn't try to guess what the author meant).

Comment: I concur that you should simply ask the author about this, but disagree that this means that the question should be closed - questions asking how to justify a claim in a mathematical text where the question-asker fears they may have misread are relatively common on MO, and people are often able to guess what was meant in cases the text was unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advices, then I will ask the author later.